# Sass - Keep original class nesting

Tags: css, webpack, sass

*Sorry for the bad title, not sure how to name it.*

While I'm compiling my scss, this:

```
.foo {
  ...
  &__bar { ... }
}
```

it turns into code below, which is what you would expect:

```css
.foo { ... }
.foo__bar { ... }
```

My problem is that I need it to be this way:

```css
.foo { ... }
.foo .foo__bar { ... }
```

with .foo selector before .foo__bar.

Is there any Webpack plugin or other solution that would help to solve my problem?

I've found two ways to achive that, but I'm wondering if there's something that would save me from additional code:

```
.foo {
  ...
  & &__bar { ... }
}

// or

.foo {
  ...
  .foo__bar { ... }
}
```

Comment: Not clear with your question, Can you explain what you need ? Do you want to minimise the code ?

Comment: Take a look at my example. There's output code I get when my code is compiled, in the box below it's what I would want it to be.

Basically, what I need is .foo class before .foo__bar selector.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to get this

.foo { ... }
.foo .foo__bar { ... }

You need to write your scss like this :

.foo {
......
  &.foo__bar {
   .......
  }
}

Please try this and see if it works ?

Comment: Sorry but your answer is not helpful, it even contains an error.

If you write:
```.foo { ...... &.foo__bar { ....... } }```
you'll get:
```.foo {...} .foo.foo__bar { ....... } ```
not what I need, which is: 
```.foo {...} .foo .foo__bar { ....... } ```
Small difference but it changes all.

I know various methods I could use writing my code to achieve what I need, it's not a problem. 

I'm looking for some Webpack option or plugin that would allow compiling my code this way by default.